# How do I join these arrays is one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, split

```
calculaNumeroDaSenha(['0110100000', '1001011111','1110001010', '0111010101','0011100110', '1010011001', '1101100100', '1011010100', '1001100111', '1000011000']);

function calculaNumeroDaSenha(senha) {

    for (let i = 0; i < senha.length; i++) {
     var dividir = senha[i].split('');

     function filtro1(modo1) {
      return modo1 == "1"
    }
    function filtro2(modo2) {
      return modo2 == "0"
    }
    etapaFinal(dividir.filter(filtro1), dividir.filter(filtro2));
    function etapaFinal(x,y) {
      var novaArray = [];
      if (x.length > y.length || x.length == y.length) {
        novaArray.push('1')}
      else {
        novaArray.push('0');
       }
       console.log(novaArray);

      };
 
    } 
  }
```

the code output looks like this:

```
 ['0']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['1']
 ['0']
```

But I want the output to come out in just an array, like this:

```
['0111111110']
```

I've already tried methods like the join() function, but it didn't work:

```
    function etapaFinal(x,y) {
      var novaArray = [];
      if (x.length > y.length || x.length == y.length) {
        novaArray.push('1')}
      else {
        novaArray.push('0');
       }
       for (let a = 0; a < novaArray.length; a++) {
        console.log(novaArray[i].join());
       }
      
      };
```

Please, if you have any idea how to do this, no matter how, help me if possible.

Comment: Which language you are talking about?

Comment: it's in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like your fundamental misunderstanding is how `.push` works. Push, as the name implies, pushes a new value to the end of the array. Thus instead of pushing to an array, what you need to do is just build up a string and then push that string at the end.

Looks like your code will either return a 1 or a 0 depending on what filter. Thus your new code can look like so:

```
function calculaNumeroDaSenha(senha) {
      let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < senha.length; i++) {
       var dividir = senha[i].split('');

       const filtro1 = (modo1) => {
        return modo1 == "1"
      }

      const filtro2 = (modo2) => {
        return modo2 == "0"
      }

      const etapaFinal = (x,y) => {
        if (x.length > y.length || x.length == y.length) {
          return '1';
        }
        else {
          return '0';
        }
      };
 
            result += etapaFinal(dividir.filter(filtro1), dividir.filter(filtro2));     
    } 
    
    return [result];
  }
```

Where if we then log it out as so:  `console.log(calculaNumeroDaSenha(['0110100000', '1001011111','1110001010', '0111010101','0011100110', '1010011001', '1101100100', '1011010100', '1001100111', '1000011000']));`

we get an array of size 1 of the following results: `['0111111110']`. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avnkj81z/

One thing I did, is I changed your inner function blocks to be defined instead using the following pattern: `const <functionName> = <(parameters)> => {...}`. This is because it makes it easier to read and you don't have one function nested in one after the other. Note that `function A(b) { returns b; }` is equivalent to `const A = (b) => { returns b;}`

Answer (score 0):

To join all the strings into one string, use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Answer (score 0):

The question is kinda vague, you need to clarify what you're looking for:

if you are looking to group an array items into one string, you would use Array.join().

```js
const arr = ['0110100000', '1001011111','1110001010', '0111010101','0011100110', '1010011001', '1101100100', '1011010100', '1001100111', '1000011000']
arr.join(''); 
// the above command would result in a single string with all array values concatenated
// "0110100000100101111111100010100111010101001110011010100110011101100100101101010010011001111000011000"
```

However if you're looking to group all array elements into one array that has a single string with all array elements grouped, you would use Array.join() followed by String.split()

```js
const arr = ['0110100000', '1001011111','1110001010', '0111010101','0011100110', '1010011001', '1101100100', '1011010100', '1001100111', '1000011000']
arr.join('').split(); 
// the above command would result in a single array with one string with all array elements grouped
// [ "0110100000100101111111100010100111010101001110011010100110011101100100101101010010011001111000011000" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the output of this code. Please look into it. It is printing your desired value.

```js
calculaNumeroDaSenha(['0110100000', '1001011111', '1110001010', '0111010101', '0011100110', '1010011001', '1101100100', '1011010100', '1001100111', '1000011000']);

function calculaNumeroDaSenha(senha) {

  var novaArray = [];
  var str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < senha.length; i++) {
    var dividir = senha[i].split('');

    function filtro1(modo1) {
      return modo1 == "1"
    }
    function filtro2(modo2) {
      return modo2 == "0"
    }
    etapaFinal(dividir.filter(filtro1), dividir.filter(filtro2));
    function etapaFinal(x, y) {
      if (x.length > y.length || x.length == y.length) {
        str += 1;
      }
      else {
        str += 0;
      }


    };

  }
  novaArray.push(str);
  console.log(novaArray);
}
```

Comment: I would like to request you to upvote my answer.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I can't, because according to overflow, I need at least 15 reputation to be able to upvote, and I'm a new user.